# c++ static or non-static templated member functions

Tags: c++, class

I have a class MyClass

```
class MyClass 
{
    template <std::size_t N>
    void MyFunc() { // Do something with N };
};
```

Then, is MyFunc a static or non-static member function?

Comment: Did you try to compile your code?

Comment: This is what I really want to know

Comment: For a `static` method, you have to put a `static` keyword ahead of its return type. The answer is so small, that I am putting as a comment and linking a duplicate for the further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a non-static member function template. If you declared it with `static` then it would be a static member function template.

`MyFunc<0>` is a non-static member function, so you would call it like so (assuming that you made it public):

```
MyClass c{};
c.MyFunc<0>();
```